# Using Capybara + Selenium, how do I select dialog box (confirm) options in the new Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, selenium, capybara, confirm, firefox4

I have done a solid amount of research for this issue and have sadly found nothing useful in regards to Firefox 4.
This option worked fine in 3.6:

```
a = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
if a.text == 'OK'
  a.dismiss
else
  a.accept
end
```

Unfortunately, simply clicking on the "OK" manually when it pops up is not an option. I've tried the various JavaScript options for this, as well (where one essentially "tricks" the prompt by sending it values beforehand).

Thank you for your time,

-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem, the only solution I've found so far is downgrading to Firefox 3.6.x